# Parsing img url with casperjs

Tags: javascript, image, url, casperjs

Im having an issue getting the image url from a website that I am trying to scrape. 
I am able to get all the text no problem with a snippet of code like this:

```
var cost = casper.fetchText('span.large');
```

However when I attempt to get the image URL im receiving an "undefined" reply in console.

```
var img = casper.getHTML('.search-product-image').src;
```

.search-product-image is the image class and I just simiply want to get the image url, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this :

```
casper.getElementAttribute('.search-product-image','src');
```

Comment: that way we have the links... but, how about the image file to be downloaded @Fanch ?

Answer (score 1):

You can include JQuery and take advantage of the syntactic sugar below or do it the vanilla way. FYI if your `getLink` has an error in it and you try to `casper.evaluate(getLinks)` it will return `null`. It will not indicate which line it's on or the error.

```
var casper = require('casper').create({
  verbose: true,
  logLevel: 'debug',
  clientScripts: ["vendor/jquery.min.js", "vendor/lodash.js"]
});

...
function getLinks(){
  // Scraping images
  $("img.ExImg.ExResult-img").each(function() {  
     imgSrc = this.src;
     tempImagesArr.push(imgSrc);
  });
}

casper.run(function() {
  var workouts = this.evaluate(getLinks);
  this.saveJSON(workouts);
  this.exit();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how casperjs is working but, you have to read casperjs docs.
http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#gethtml

getHTML function is returning html value in container. So you have split src value in this string. Or you can use just querySelector.

Try this code :

```
 var img = document.querySelector('.search-product-image').src;
```

if there are lot of element in your document, you have to use **document.querySelectorAll('.search-product-image')[0]**

Comment: This would only work inside `casper.evaluate(function(){/* here */})`!